# Bundling method wrappers

Tags: python, class, methods, import, module

I am trying to create a class that would bundle all my wrappers. I am trying to create custom etree methods which I could use across all the projects I make.

When I try to do the following I get a name error.

```
class ObjectWrapper(object):
    from lxml import etree

    @classmethod
    def stringify(cls, root):
        return etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)

    @classmethod
    def node_creator(cls, parent, child):
        ch_node = etree.Element(child)
        parent.append(ch_node)
        print "Child Node Created"
        return ch_node
```

Consider this class to be in the following structure.

```
  TopModule
      |
      |
      |
      |_
         object_wrapper.py
                |
                |
                |
                |_
                   ObjectWrapper()
```

When I do a from TopModule.object_wrapper import ObjectWrapper, I get an error saying

```
Name error: global name "etree" is not defined
```

The same happens if I do a global import and make the classmethods into a staticmethod.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: shouldn't `from lxml import etree` be above your `class` or in `__init__`?

Comment: Real quick, in that method, before return, try `global etree`. May be a scoping issue due to `etree` being declared in the class but not scoped to the method

Comment: @Vizjerei Yes I agree. But I don't want to have a global import. Consider object_wrapper.py as a collection of classes with wrappers. I am trying to do the imports in specific classes. (I may be wrong in what I am doing, I just want to know if this is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a scoping issue.
etree was defined in the class, but not scoped in the methods.
To get around this, declare `global ET` in the methods so that they have knowledge of the variable. In this case `lxml.etree` must be imported `as` something so that it can be referenced using `global`. If you don't want to use `global`, declare `from lxml import etree` above and outside the `class` all together.

```
class ObjectWrapper(object):
    import lxml.etree as ET

    @classmethod
    def stringify(cls, root):
        global ET
        return ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)

    @classmethod
    def node_creator(cls, parent, child):
        global ET
        ch_node = ET.Element(child)
        parent.append(ch_node)
        print "Child Node Created"
        return ch_node
```

Or another option....

```
from lxml import etree
class ObjectWrapper(object):

    @classmethod
    def stringify(cls, root):
        return etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)

    @classmethod
    def node_creator(cls, parent, child):
        ch_node = etree.Element(child)
        parent.append(ch_node)
        print "Child Node Created"
        return ch_node
```

Comment: Declaring global doesn't help me. Same `Name error`.

Whereas the global import always work.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the `import` as well? I tested both of the examples I posted and both ran without a `NameError`

Comment: Yes I changed the import. The editor(IntelliJ) reports it as `Global variable ET is undefined at module level.` and it returns me a `Name Error`

Comment: That's strange. If that's the case use the 2nd example I provided and declare the import outside of the `class`

Comment: Brings me back to the question, can we use an import within a class? Seems no.

Comment: You can. You can declare an import anywhere. Where you declare the import dictates the scope of that import. Declaring global inside of the classmethod will make it so that it checks at the global level for that variable first, in this case checking the class. I'm not sure why IntelliJ would report a NameError for my first example, Eclipse, Notepad, even command line doesn't have an issue with it.